# how to run bower install inside subfolder in Docker

Tags: angularjs, docker, dockerfile

```
--myproject
---app
----bower.json
----index.html
---package.json
```

My project folder structure is like that. What I want is I want to run `bower install` command in docker file before `npm install`. Following is my `Dockerfile`. Got stuck how to go sub folder and run `bower install`. Thanks.

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###
FROM node:latest as builder
LABEL auther="PPShein"
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN gulp default
```

Comment: `RUN cd myproject/app && bower install` is no good?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

`RUN cd app && bower install`

Or

```
WORKDIR app
bower install
```

this changes the pwd for all following commands, which you may not want.

PS. Careful with `COPY . .`, it may overwrite what you just built.

Comment: Agree about that final COPY. You should just run `COPY . .` once and you won't have to run `COPY package.json package.json`, it will be included. You'll also need to do this before running bower.

Comment: `RUN cd app && bower install` is not working and second one either.

Comment: `Step 8/9 : RUN cd /myapp/app && bower install
 ---> Running in f9578b28c747
/bin/sh: 1: bower: not found`

Comment: you have to install bower first `npm install -g bower`